# How to find client_customer_id of linked accounts, in Google Adwords?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am building an application that is using Google Adwords API.
I am asking the user to sign in with his Google Account and grant me permission to use his adwords Accounts.
When the user logs in with Google, I am getting his accounts using `googleads.adwords`

```
from googleads import oauth2, adwords

client = adwords.AdWordsClient(developer_token, oauth2_client, 'test')
offline_conversion_feed_service = client.GetService('CustomerService', version='v201809')
customers = offline_conversion_feed_service.getCustomers()
```

I need to find all the MCC accounts and their linked accounts.

In `customers` I have all the accounts and their `client_customer_id`, but I cannot determine which account is linked with which MCC.

My question is, how to determine which accounts are linked with which ?